# Show keys pressed in Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard

In Windows there is a program called *Keyboard Jedi* that shows what keys are pressed on the keyboard.

Is there an equivalent for Linux?

Comment: I was looking for something that helps with screen casts...screenkey seem like what I wanted.

Comment: Xev os great option and probably  is already installed onyour machine

Comment: I am happy to find this question. It should be reopened as [on-topic] because it is about "computer software" - similar as [software-to-show-typed-keys-on-the-screen](https://superuser.com/questions/311199/software-to-show-typed-keys-on-the-screen/311221#311221).

Comment: See also [Ubuntu: show what keys are pressed in real-time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1197651/ubuntu-show-what-keys-are-pressed-in-real-time). I find the https://www.keyboardtester.com/ and `evtest` answers there to be very useful, and both of them work.

Comment: Since this question is closed, this is probably the best place to add any new answers that may come up: [Unix & Linux: How to detect global key presses](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120199/how-to-detect-global-key-presses)

Answer (score 205, accepted):

Others have mentioned `xev`, which is good when you're running X11.  When you're at the console, however, `showkey` is what you want.

And if you’re at an SSH session or a real terminal, you can use `/usr/lib/ncurses/examples/demo_altkeys` (available in Debian in the ncurses-examples package).

Note that xev for "a" gives 38, while showkey for "a" gives 30, because xev reports scancodes, whereas showkey by default reports keycodes.

Comment: Neither work in SSH terminal.

Comment: @anatolytechtonik: Guess you gotta get a new Innernet :(

Comment: @anatolytechtonik For me, xev works fine via ssh. Did you add -X or -Y to the ssh options on the ssh command line?

Comment: @ChristianHujer, -X -Y means X11 forwarding (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425820/difference-between-ssh-x-and-ssh-y). There is no X11 server on my machine (I use PuTTY), so `xev` doesn't apply, and `showkey` gives `Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console`.

Comment: @anatolytechtonik Yes, if you use PuTTY, or any environment where X11 forwarding doesn't work, it will not work. Your statement just sounded like it would never work in a terminal, and that's simply not true. `xev` will work in `ssh` in a terminal if X11 forwarding is enabled and functional.

Comment: to work around `showkey` giving the error about not getting a file descriptor (like in comment by @anatolytechtonik ), try `sudo showkey`

Comment: Why do these two approaches give different results? Example: `xev` for "a" gives 38, while `showkey` for "a" gives 30.

Comment: @Johann `xev` reports scancodes whereas `showkey` by default reports keycodes. `sudo showkey -s` reports scancodes.

Comment: `locate demo_altkeys` might point to the matching binary in any UNIX system, if it's there and that the file database is up-to-date (`updatedb` if you have the relevant privileges)

Comment: Use `libinput debug-events` which is also "Wayland" compatible, see [man(1)](https://www.mankier.com/1/libinput-debug-events).

Comment: But it can not show timing information. [xev](https://superuser.com/questions/248517/show-keys-pressed-in-linux/248518#248518) does.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent `showkey` from timing out after 10 seconds without doing ASCII dump mode?

Comment: Only `showkey -a` works over an SSH PTY or a serial terminal (`/dev/ttyS`_n_). It's sensible, as the scancode/keycode/emission byte sequence is handled on the client end, in the TTY emulator (or hardware, if you're a fan of Retrocomputing.SO). You put these sequences into `.inputrc` for e.g. bash, and other readline-happy stuff. The remote X stuff works differently: [e.g., Windows-based] X server has access to your raw keyboard (Windows reserves some chords, tho), and sends scancodes. Over `ssh -Y` or TCP, all the same. There's also the terminfo DB (demo_altkeys), but this margin is too narr..

Comment: Summary: `showkey` doesn't work; `sudo showkey` works great and shows numeric keycodes, `sudo showkey -s` shows hex scancodes, and `sudo showkey -a` shows ASCII keycodes, including the actual letter or character pressed, which is the most human-readable. Note: to exit the `sudo showkey -a` option, use Ctrl + D. Ctrl + C works in most of the other tests, but NOT in that one.

Comment: I added my summary above to [my answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/683257/114401). Unfortunately, this question is closed or I'd have added it here.

Answer (score 88):

Also [screenkey](https://gitlab.com/screenkey/screenkey), a screencast tool that displays keys being pressed on-screen.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't show me keys like volume up/down.

Comment: For me, this shows both brightness and volume adjustments. Great little program overall!

Comment: The version in Debian Stretch repositories is ancient (and Stretch is stable for only, idk, 2 months maybe?). Use the Github version to get some settings.

Comment: Repo was migrated to [Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/wavexx/screenkey).

Answer (score 45):

```
 chris@retina:~$ xinput list
 ⎡ Virtual core pointer                     id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
 ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer               id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
 ⎜   ↳ bcm5974                                  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
 ⎜   ↳ Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:1028  id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
 ⎣ Virtual core keyboard                    id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
     ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard              id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
     ↳ Power Button                             id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
     ↳ Power Button                             id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
     ↳ Sleep Button                             id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
     ↳ FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)            id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
     ↳ Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad    id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
     ↳ daskeyboard                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
     ↳ daskeyboard                              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
 chris@retina:~$ xinput test 14
 key release 36 
 key press   43 
 hkey release 43 
 key press   26 
 ekey release 26 
 key press   46 
 lkey release 46 
 key press   46 
 lkey release 46 
 key press   32 
 okey release 32 
 key press   37 
 key press   54 
 ^C
 chris@retina:~$
```

Comment: xev failed to show me Mx Anywhere 2 mouse buttons, this method displayed correct button.

Answer (score 43):

There is the `xev` program for graphic mode - see [the man page of xev](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xev).

On Ubuntu/Debian it is packed into the `x11-utils` package.

Comment: Using this at the command line and pushing the key that I thought wasn't working, made the key start working. Wild, I'll take it!

Comment: Add it displays timing information (in contrast to `showkey`).

Answer (score 42):

The better command that I know for this functionality is [`showkey`](http://kbd-project.org/manpages/man1/showkey.1.html), with parameter `-a`.

You could try, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to exit:

```
showkey -a
```

Comment: `showkey` is already mentioned in the earlier answers.

Comment: But the addition `-a` is useful, showing how to use the command. But should be a comment then.

Comment: `sudo showkey -a` works with ssh too.

Comment: Can you add to your answer why "`-a`" is better? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, would this work without `sudo`? Does it? (Please respond by [editing your answer](https://superuser.com/posts/921637/edit), not here in comments (as appropriate)).

Comment: For instance, it doesn't output anything for "Shift + Ctrl + C", whereas without `-a` it does.

Comment: Without the `-a` option I was getting the error: `Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console` when using this over ah SSH connection.

Comment: The `-a` flag has no timeout, either. Which is nice if you want to use it in a script.

Comment: This does not display modifier keys in isolation, e.g Meta/Win or shift

Answer (score 40):

If you are looking for something that graphically shows you what key is pressed currently (perhaps for the corner of a screencast), [key-mon](https://github.com/scottkirkwood/key-mon) might be the ticket.

Comment: If you can find the increasingly difficult-to-find Python 2.x and PyGTK (GTK+ 2.x) dependencies, I'd recommend key-mon as the nicest-looking option for screencasts. (I'd try my hand at porting to Python 3.x and GTK+ 3.x, but I have too much else on my plate that's more urgently needed.)

Comment: key-mon is pretty cumbersome to install unfortunately, code hasn't been updated/maintained in over 8 years and dependencies aren't easy to find as @ssokolow mentioned. The only alternative is screenkey which is also a bit weird but does work.

Answer (score 24):

You can also use `evtest`. In some situations, it is better than `xev` as it shows keys even when a key is already captured.

To install under Ubuntu/[Linux Mint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint), do

```
sudo apt-get install evtest
```

to run `sudo evtest` and pick a device number.

Example output:

```
$ sudo evtest
No device specified, trying to scan all of /dev/input/event*
Available devices:
/dev/input/event0:    Lid Switch
/dev/input/event1:    Power Button
/dev/input/event2:    Power Button
/dev/input/event3:    AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
/dev/input/event4:    ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad
/dev/input/event5:    Logitech Logitech G930 Headset
/dev/input/event6:    Video Bus
/dev/input/event7:    HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8
/dev/input/event8:    HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7
/dev/input/event9:    HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3
/dev/input/event10:    HDA Intel PCH Headphone
/dev/input/event11:    HDA Intel PCH Mic
/dev/input/event12:    WebCam SC-10HDP12B24N
/dev/input/event13:    ELAN Touchscreen
Select the device event number [0-13]: 5
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x46d product 0xa1f version 0x101
Input device name: "Logitech Logitech G930 Headset"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 114 (KEY_VOLUMEDOWN)
    Event code 115 (KEY_VOLUMEUP)
    Event code 163 (KEY_NEXTSONG)
    Event code 164 (KEY_PLAYPAUSE)
    Event code 165 (KEY_PREVIOUSSONG)
    Event code 256 (BTN_0)
    Event code 257 (BTN_1)
    Event code 258 (BTN_2)
    Event code 259 (BTN_3)
    Event code 260 (BTN_4)
    Event code 261 (BTN_5)
    Event code 262 (BTN_6)
    Event code 263 (BTN_7)
    Event code 264 (BTN_8)
    Event code 265 (BTN_9)
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
Properties:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Event: time 1412585327.807585, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value c00b5
Event: time 1412585327.807585, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 163 (KEY_NEXTSONG), value 1
Event: time 1412585327.807585, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1412585327.927557, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value c00b5
Event: time 1412585327.927557, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 163 (KEY_NEXTSONG), value 0
Event: time 1412585327.927557, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

Comment: Doesn't work with SSH. Looks like there is no `/dev/input` at all there.

Answer (score 13):

If you're at a shell prompt, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> then the key of interest to see what the output is. For example, on my system, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> then <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> shows `^[[C` which means Escape, Left Bracket, C.

As others have mentioned, `xev` is the way to go for X11.

Comment: But "^[[C" is not a key. A terminal escape sequence, rather, maybe?

Comment: Indeed. It's `Esc+[C`. `showkey -a` would also show escape sequence for a pressed special key + codes for each element of an escape sequence.

Comment: Yes, it's an escape sequence that pressing Right Arrow produces on my system at the shell prompt in the terminal I'm using.

Answer (score 7):

You'd be wanting [xev](http://www.xfree86.org/4.2.0/xev.1.html).

Answer (score 7):

```
xev | grep 'keycode'
    state 0x0, keycode 36 (keysym 0xff0d, Return), same_screen YES,
    state 0x0, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    state 0x4, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    state 0x0, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    state 0x4, keycode 52 (keysym 0x7a, z), same_screen YES,
    state 0x4, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    state 0x0, keycode 54 (keysym 0x63, c), same_screen YES,
    state 0x0, keycode 52 (keysym 0x7a, z), same_screen YES,
    state 0x0, keycode 54 (keysym 0x63, c), same_screen YES,
```

Comment: `xev -event keyboard` reports only keyboard events.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to see a human-friendly-ish output of the key pressed, you can use this:

`xev | sed -n 's/[ ]*state.* \([^ ]*\)).*/\1/p'`

Note you'll get the keypress output on both keydown and keyup.