# Software to show typed keys on the screen

Tags: windows, linux, macos, software-rec, keyboard

[image: a video capture]

Just as the capture shows, when you type something using the keyboard, a big label appears at the bottom of the screen showing the keys you typed.

I use Windows & Linux, so I just want to know if there is a similar software to do that?

Comment: What software does this on mac?  I'd like to try it out

Comment: I think I've seen something like this used in video lectures from http://cs75.tv and I think it was mac software, too.

Comment: @CamelBlues - [KeyCastr](http://stephendeken.net/software/keycastr/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Linux check Screenkey: https://launchpad.net/screenkey

Answer (score 3):

On Windows there is [Carnac the Magnificent](http://carnackeys.com/).

> A keyboard logging and presentation utility for presentations, screencasts, and to help you become a better keyboard user.

Install via Chocolatey:

```
choco install carnac
```

Or Scoop:

```
scoop install carnac
```

Source on GitHub:

https://github.com/Code52/carnac

Answer (score 0):

There is [Key Jedi](http://osherove.com/blog/2007/6/3/train-to-be-a-keyboard-master-with-keyboard-jedi.html)

> Key Jedi allows learning and training to use keyboard shortcuts. **It can be used in presentations, screencasts and videos**, as well as when working with someone else on the same machine to teach new shortcuts. It shows a visual list of shortcuts as you type them, no matter what application you work in. It is free, simple and quick to use.

<sub>Emphasis mine</sub>

Comment: Hmm.  Immediately crashes on my machine, so I can't check it out =(  Any idea?