# How to stop run the screenkey

Tags: linux, linux-mint, software-rec

Once I found the software to show my typed keys [here](https://superuser.com/questions/311199/software-to-show-typed-keys-on-the-screen#366778), I started to be in trouble because there's no turn-off button in the screen nor in its `man`, and it has been followed me to everywhere as

[image: screenshot]

I could just ran `sudo kill` on the process but this means I'll be showing my sudo password.

I'm using Linux Mint 18.3, both solutions as a native command from ScreeKey or a way to show a turn-off button on Operational System Panel will help my problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can exit from [Screenkey](https://gitlab.com/screenkey/screenkey) by **right**-clicking on its status icon and selecting "Quit":

[image: screenshot]

If you're using GNOME/Unity and cannot see any status icon please make sure the python-appindicator package is installed. Run the following inside a terminal to install as required:

```
sudo apt install python-appindicator
```

On any other desktop system Screenkey uses the regular system tray. If you don't have a systray or you cannot quit an existing Screenkey, use the following command in a terminal to kill it:

```
pkill -f screenkey
```

Comment: Dude, the status icon does not appear, even after the python-appindicator instaled and system reboot. However the `pkill` works to kill and not provide my pass, thank you

Answer (score 4):

```
pkill -f screenkey
```

Source: [Project Site](https://gitlab.com/screenkey/screenkey#id15)

Answer (score 0):

First, install `htop`:

```
sudo apt-get install htop
```

Then, type `htop` on your terminal to enter the `htop` environment, then press `F3` to search for ***screenkey***, when you found it, press `F9` to kill its process.