# Show keys pressed in custom console

Tags: linux, bash, keyboard, terminal, remote-access

I have a custom client that connects to remote Ubuntu via websocket and runs bash there. But keys like Del, Arrows etc. don't work. How can I output what is being received on the server side? None of the solutions mentioned in [show keys pressed in linux](https://superuser.com/questions/248517/show-keys-pressed-in-linux) work.

**UPDATE**: I first asked question about SSH, but later realized that I am probably not using SSH.

**UPDATE2**: What have I tried.

```
# showkey
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console

# evtest
No device specified, trying to scan all of /dev/input/event*
USAGE:
 Capture mode:
   evtest [--grab] /dev/input/eventX
     --grab  grab the device for exclusive access

 Query mode: (check exit code)
   evtest --query /dev/input/eventX <type> <value>

<type> is one of: EV_KEY, EV_SW, EV_LED, EV_SND
<value> can either be a numerical value, or the textual name of the
key/switch/LED/sound being queried (e.g. SW_DOCK).


# ls /dev/input
ls: cannot access /dev/input: No such file or directory


# stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 300; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc ixany imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke
```

Basically, I need something like this:

[image: termbox keyboard demo]

**UPDATE3**: The communication between console client and server is done through websockets in Go. Sources - [client](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/7edb3468e56b615eecdbf170c0e0301b4001edbc/client.go#L1214) and [server](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/34c7d9bdeb79ba2e46eb31256f4a4731265b09ec/lxd/container_exec.go#L77).

Comment: You've given half the question: we do not know what you tried and what the result was.  If you were connected as a (pseudo)terminal, the ctrl+V part would tell you something, as would "stty -a".

Comment: How are you connecting to the server? Are you connecting to port 23? That means you're using telnet. If you don't know whether you're using SSH or telnet then I think you may have bitten off more than you can chew! What you are essentially doing by connecting like this is writing a terminal emulator. You need to support everything that a terminal emulator needs to support. For example, from a Windows machine you might use PuTTY to connect to a remote Unix machine. PuTTY is a terminal emulator, so you would need to do everything that PuTTY does. So you need to implement the TELNET protocol.

Comment: @ThomasDickey, edited question.

Comment: @Sam, the code is here https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/34c7d9bdeb79ba2e46eb31256f4a4731265b09ec/lxd/container_exec.go#L77 - it uses websockets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result showing `stty -a` was promising, but neither the question nor the other answer pointed to the usual way to find what is sent by a special key such as <kbd>Del</kbd>, <kbd>Left-cursor</kbd>, etc.

It is unclear which "Del" OP is referring to.  I have both <kbd>Delete</kbd> and <kbd>Del</kbd> keys on my keyboard (on the editing- and numeric-keypads).  Both could send a series of data bytes beginning with <kbd>ESC</kbd> (the ASCII escape character).  That is, in a regular terminal.

However, the question referred to [websocket](https://www.websocket.org/), which sounds as if this is running in a web browser.  The screenshot shows some type of onscreen keyboard, with `DEL` in the editing keypad.

If the implementation is complete, one would expect something like this to be sent to the shell when *pressing* that key, if you first press <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>:

```
^[[3~
```

The `^[` is the echoed ASCII escape character (<kbd>control</kbd><kbd>`[`</kbd>).  You need the <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> *lnext* character to prevent the shell from interpreting it or throwing it away.

The `lnext` (literal next) setting is a feature of any [termios](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/termios.h.html) which you are likely to encounter, but oddly not mentioned in the POSIX standard except as reserved for an extension (see the mention of `VLNEXT`).  However, since this is tagged for linux, the Linux documentation is what you can use for a reference:

- [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tcsetattr.3.html)

  > The termios functions describe a general terminal interface that is
  >   provided to control asynchronous communications ports.
- [stty(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html)

  > Print or change terminal characteristics.

You can see it in the output of [`stty -a`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/stty.html), i.e., in the fourth output line in this example:

```
$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 40; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^H; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke
```

Comment: What is this Control+V mechanism? Is it something supported by all Linuxes?

Comment: yes - it is a feature of all Unix-like systems.

Comment: I don't see anything when I press F1, Arrows etc. after Ctrl-V, so that 100% means that my client doesn't send it, right?

Comment: That sounds right - the keyboard implementation may be incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to take a step back and think about what you're trying to do. You weren't clear on how you are connecting to the server over WebSockets. I'm assuming you are connecting to a WebSocket server which is proxying the connection to the telnet port, is that right (because WebSockets can only connect to WebSockets)? You may want to take a look at the [Websockify](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify) project which has an example VT100-compatible telnet client. You could base your project off that.

Comment: Here is the client code. https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/7edb3468e56b615eecdbf170c0e0301b4001edbc/client.go#L1214 I need to look deeper for the server part.