# Dealing with a faulty keyboard - ^[[17~

Tags: linux, keyboard

I have a problem with a faulty laptop keyboard. When I open the terminal I can see:

```
 ^[[17~^[[17~^[[17~^[[17~user@computer:~$ ~~~~~~~~ [...]
```

and so on with an infinite number of tilde symbols.

xev shows 72-keycode events.
However if I leave open a gedit window, no character appears.

How can I detect which key is being "pressed"?

Comment: It's F6, found by typing `xxd` and examining the input as each key is pressed. Some keys will bypass the input buffer, but most (including F6) are read. See also the answers to [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/248517/show-keys-pressed-in-linux).

Answer (score 0):

> `xev` shows 72-keycode events. […] How can I detect which key is being "pressed"?

In my Kubuntu 16.04.3 LTS `xev` shows not only keykodes. The key with keycode 72, while being constantly pressed, makes `xev` repeat the following output:

```
KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x2c4, subw 0x0, time 2544694, (173,-21), root:(173,8),
    state 0x10, keycode 72 (keysym 0xffc3, F6), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x2c4, subw 0x0, time 2544732, (173,-21), root:(173,8),
    state 0x10, keycode 72 (keysym 0xffc3, F6), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Important line with explanation:

```
state 0x10, keycode 72 (keysym 0xffc3, F6), same_screen YES,
  keycode obviously ^^                 ^^ human-readable name
```

So it's <kbd>F6</kbd>.