# fedora 25 map winkey into control

Tags: linux, xmodmap

This is the result of `xmodmap -pm`:

```
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_L (0x42),  Control_R (0x69), Control_L (0x85),  Control_R (0x86)
mod4        Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
```

I have this `.xmodmap`:

```
clear mod4
add control = Super_L
```

After I run this, it changes my command modifier list, but the windows key doesn't actually behave as control. Why? Can I fix this?

Comment: which windows manager do you use? default WM uses wayland, so do you use xorg or not?

Comment: I was not able to find my windows manager. default for fedora 25 I think

Comment: from the [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/167959/64187) - for your case try 'setxkbmap -option ctrl:swap_lwin_lctl'

Comment: after that command I got of xmodmap -pm:                                           
    control     Control_R (0x69),  Control_L (0x85)                                   
    mod4        Super_L (0x25),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)               so looks like it changed nothing. I also tried this option: altwin:ctrl_win. The same result

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to do that with gnome-tweak-tool. There is an option there in Typing section. in 'Ctrl key position' section select checkbox 'Swap Left Win key with Left Ctrl key'

Comment: Please [edit] and document what option there is and what you changed it to.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @user2889981 in https://superuser.com/a/1193894/1032352, it can be done in [Gnome Tweaks](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tweaks) app. In Fedora 29 it's in Keyboard & Mouse > Additional Layout Options (button next to Overview Shortcut) > Ctrl position > check next to Swap Left Win with Left Ctrl

Answer (score 0):

Ok, on my system

Version

```
~$cat /etc/fedora-release 
Fedora release 25 (Twenty Five)
```

Window manager

```
~$env | grep -i desktop
DESKTOP_SESSION=gnome
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=gnome
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME
```

Keyboard settings

```
~$setxkbmap -print
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+ru:2+us:3+inet(evdev)"   };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

with more or less accurate physical representation of the keyboard (PC105)
[image]

The command

```
setxkbmap -option altwin:ctrl_win
```

replaces 'win' key and makes it 'ctrl' key.

What has been changed after the executions is

```
~$setxkbmap -print
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+ru:2+us:3+inet(evdev)+altwin(ctrl_win)"  };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

I have one display, setxkbmap have display and device options, it may be important.

to clear options 'setxkbmap -option'
to restore options later seems to be better to use 'setxkbmap -query' instead of 'setxkbmap -print' before

more sophisticated replacement tricks with setxkbmap in the answer [Adding custom setxkbmap options](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212560/64187) and in the [complicated article](http://madduck.net/docs/extending-xkb/).

Other possible replacements, according to the answer from [Rebind Alt key to win using setxkbmap?](https://askubuntu.com/a/29734/275037) are available to see with:

```
grep alt /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst | grep win
```

Comment: this is my keyboard: http://www.lenovo.com/images/gallery/1060x596/lenovo-laptop-ideapad-510s-14-red-keyboard-3.jpg. everything else is like yours. that option doesn't work

Comment: @user2889981 interesting, my is lenovo g570. Does the key something at all for you - in gnome default action is to show desktops and that application shortcuts. Try to bind the key for any action - does it work - in settings keyboard.

Comment: @user2889981 also try the to check the key code like in the [answer](https://superuser.com/a/834336/312809) , my gets 133

Comment: I disabled default action for it. the code 133 is like for you

Comment: I enabled it now. tried again your solution. doesn't work

Comment: I'm not able to bind this key to any action. When I press it it is not get selected as hot key

Comment: @user2889981 For me it does not matter is default action enabled or not, when applied default action just stops working, when I reset the setxkbmap options it just starts working gnome way again. Yes, not assigning to actions seems to be normal behaviour. what 'setxkbmap -query' shows you?

Comment: $ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us

Comment: @user2889981 after applying 'setxkbmap -option altwin:ctrl_win' try 'xev | grep key' what it shows you - mine detects pressing ctrl and winkey  like 'state 0x4, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES' and 'state 0x0, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 37'

Comment: and after I execute your command: rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us
options:    altwin:ctrl_win

Comment: xev | grep key returns the same as for you

Comment: @user2889981 hm, how do you check then if it works as ctrl or not - I press  win+a - to see if it works as ctrl-a, and other hotkeys ctrl-hotkeys I use. But seems to be interesting magic

Comment: I tried ctr-r and win-r in konsole to search in history. also tried ctrl-a

Comment: @user2889981 works for me in gnome console. I'm out of ideas then at the moment.