# evtest(or alternative) for windows

Tags: linux, windows, windows-7, keyboard

My laptop has been behaving weird lately, with me finding that it usually registers the down key being pressed by itself(the page scrolls to the bottom on Chrome).

In a Linux distro, I'd use `evtest` to confirm this, with the down key actually registering as being pressed on the main(i.e. included) keyboard(or whichever key I wasn't expecting.)

What are the options for Windows, though? There's no `evtest` here. What command/program can I use to troubleshoot the issue? I am 99% sure the issue is a physical one(I have an antivirus suite installed that should alert me if something funky was going on software-wise). If I only knew which key was causing this I could troubleshoot it.

Comment: For those curious, I went to my Linux distro, used evtest and found it was the Page Down key that was at fault(I tortured my down arrow key for nothing!). Apparently a dust bunny trapped in there was causing the key to repeatedly trigger at random.

Comment: I am glad you fixed this.  I don't think that there is a windows tool to do this.  I have (more than once) whipped one up in c or c# and threw it away after figuring out the problem.  It's a shame.. but whatever.. it is what it is.  In the future, you can probably use WSL (built into windows) to gain access to your Linux toolset without needing to boot into a different distro.  Good luck and I am glad you figured it out.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Why not put it on GitHub with a basic released exe? I'm sure a lot of people would find that quite useful. Heck, even an `evtest` clone would have been perfect for me here.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Ah WSL... maybe. I am using Windows 7 though, so that's not really a simple option for me.

Comment: After a little more digging, this [appears to be a dupe](https://superuser.com/questions/248517/show-keys-pressed-in-linux) and there are indeed tools to help :)  They closed it as "off topic" but there are still a lot of good suggestions. I don't understand why they closed it but I am not an admin here and I am sure they had reasons.